# How to configure Workbench to allow author to publish own content without moderation?

Tags: 7, nodes, workbench

I have author role for creating content. This content is moderated by moderators. Now I would like to add second role super author. Super author can published his own content without moderation. How should I configure Workbench for this?

**EDIT**

There is a WB Access permission for this:

> Bypass moderation restrictions

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this issue, it discusses this topic: https://www.drupal.org/node/1338750

As it seems the requested functionality will not be included.

Comment: Hi JPustekuchen, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)